# The number of relative prices without money

Tags: money, price

So recently I am reading a lot of monetary literature and this comes up when they talk about the unit of account function of money:

$$(n / 2)(n-1)$$

Can we prove this or where does it come from and what is the intuition here?

Comment: What are you reading exactly? please clarify this question

Comment: Bofinger, P., 2001. Monetary policy: goals, institutions, strategies, and instruments. and Issing, O., 2011. Einführung in die Geldtheorie. for example mention this formula.

Comment: I think more usually in mathematics it is written as n(n-1)/2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula you wrote comes from the mathematical concept of **combination.**

In mathematics, a *combination* is a selection of items from a set that has distinct members, such that the **order of selection does not matter**: you take a certain number of objects from a set, without caring of the order of the selection.

The **number of combinations of $n$ things taken $k$ at a time,** without repetition (each element is taken only once), can be indicated as $C^n_k$, and it is equal to the so-called *binomial coefficient*, indicated as $\binom{n}{k}$:

$$C^n_k=\binom{n}{k}\equiv \frac {n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$

In our case, of an **exchange economy with $n$ goods,** the number of markets (the exchange spots of two goods) is given by the combinations of $n$ objects taken two at a time, that is:

$\;$

$$C^n_2= \binom{n}{2}=\frac {n!}{2!(n-2)!}= \frac {n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)... 2\cdot 1}{2(n-2)(n-3)... 2 \cdot 1}=\frac {n(n-1)}{2}\qquad (1)$$
$\;$

If you consider relative prices regardless of the order of the goods, that is, given two goods $A$ and $B$, you consider $\frac{p_A}{p_B}$ and $\frac{p_B}{p_A}$ to be the same price, the number of relative prices is also given by the formula $(1)$ ($p_A$ and $p_B$ are the nominal prices of $A$ and $B$).

$\;$

You can see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very clear explenation!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: I do have one more question: If we consider an exchange economy with $n$ goods and $one$ universal used medium of exchange in which every other good is priced can we formulate it also with the binomial coefficient (what would $k$ be in this case)? Intuitively I get that it is $n-1$ because every other good is priced in that specific good beside the good it self.

Comment: I agree with you, if you are saying that the only prices you consider are $\frac{p_i}{p_U}$, $i=1,...,n-1$ (the goods except the universal medium),   where $p_U$ is the price (arbitrary) of the 'universal medium of exchange'.

Comment: Now I am interested in a way to proof that $(n(n-1))/2 > n-1$ holds true. I would like to make the case that an economy with one universal medium of exchange is more efficient then a pure barter economy.

Comment: This true for $n>2$. 
Indeed, for $n\neq 1$ we have, (dividing both sides by $n-1$),  $\frac {n(n-1)}{2}>n-1  \iff n/2>1 \iff n>2$

Comment: Oh now its obvious for me. Thank you very much! I think this is all. Have a nice day :)

Comment: You are welcome:)